# SET SQL_MODE affect other / all databases?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database project that calls for an unusual need to set all table primary keys to auto increment from zero. I've been reading up on SET SQL_MODE - and the possible issues it might cause. If I run this command, will it affect the other databases on the server? Can I have databases using different SQL_MODE's on the same server?

Comment: `The MySQL server can operate in different SQL modes, and can apply these modes differently for different clients, depending on the value of the sql_mode system variable.`. `Setting the GLOBAL variable requires the SUPER privilege and affects the operation of all clients that connect from that time on. Setting the SESSION variable affects only the current client. Each client can change its session sql_mode value at any time.`  See [5.1.7 Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is becoming a bit more clear for me. If I set it per session, I assume I must run the command every time I use the database? If I'm a user with access to other DB's will this sql mode apply to other databases I have access privileges to? I've read a lot of comments saying this is bad practice, but why is it? I'm making a DB for a long term project, so stability of the design and how it's accessed matter to me, so all these negative comments about it have me worried.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-sql-modes.html#faq-mysql-sql-mode-dependency

> **A.3.4.**
>
> Question: Is the mode dependent on the database or connection?
>
> Answer: A mode is not linked to a particular database. Modes can be set
>   locally to the session (connection), or globally for the server. you
>   can change these settings using SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='modes'.